# VB6: "Visual basic has stopped working"

Tags: vb6

I have a problem with my microsoft visual basic 6 ide, as it's giving me "Visual basic has stopped working" error, from the very start when trying to open my vb project. It is not a code related problem as the same error pumps out when trying to open a perfectly good older working project. Also, trying to open the ide, in order to create a new fresh project, that it lets me.

The problem appeared, when, while debugging project code, I stopped it (closed the ide) without pressing the stop debugging button.So I am not shure but the problem might be from the fact that I suddenly closed the ide, without saving any changes I made(?). After that, when I tried open the project again, it gives me that error. I restarted, but the error persists.
I researched, the closer i found is here : 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/359453bd-c8b3-41a7-a668-2c3755dcacef/visual-basic-has-stopped-workingvb60?forum=vbgeneral

But still no solution. How can I restore my project?It was working just fine until the incident.
I mention that OS is Windows 7.

Thank you.

Comment: VB6 sometimes leaves invalid state behind. I haven't seen the exact problem you describe, but it doesn't surprise me either. Since this is not limited to a single project, it could be registry data. For instance, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/38644469/3195477 for a similar kind of issue.

Answer (score 2):

Something to try, in case it's crashing trying to execute some code in your project on startup. This could happen in things like user controls if there's code that executed when it's rendered at design time.

1. Open VB6
2. Create a new Standard EXE
3. Click Tools|Options
4. Click the General tab
5. Select Break on All Errors
6. Click OK
7. Close VB6, without saving the new project that was created, then try opening it with your project

You can't get into the options without a project loaded so that's why you need to create a new one. The option is global so it will still be set when you open your project.

If there's an error in your code that's causing the error then this should allow the IDE to break on the error so you can see where it is.

You could also try deleting the .vbw file before opening your project, just in case it's corrupt.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer, I am in the process of trying your suggestion, but can you please tell me, is there any possibility that the ide crashes because of some automatic updates windows 7 made? my point is, is there any chance that this is related to new updates triggering some compatibility issues?  Thank you.

Comment: If the crash only happens when opening a specific project then I wouldn't think it's related to a Windows update. I use Windows 7 64-bit as my development machine and haven't had any issues with the VB6 IDE. I haven't run a Windows update in a month or two though.

Comment: Hi, The ide crashes for any project I try to open. That is how I got to the conclusion that it is not a code related problem at all. And where I looked on the internet, everybody was talking about compatibility issues which I find weird because the ide was working fine. Anyway, meanwhile, the ide recovered, don't know why and how. Thank you for your collaboration.

Comment: I asked about the updates because, there were updates in my case and removed them .But still...anyway...I will try to see why it is working again now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and by accident and playing around I solved it by opening  Tools>> Options>> General  and then I unchecked Background Compile.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes temporary files are the cause of malfunction in various apps, one of the first things I do is delete all of them from the windows temp folder and from the current user temp folder; it is also a good idea to have a look at the registry and do a standard cleanup.

Better yet, after these empty the recycle bin and do a defrag.