# VB6 and windows 10 screen blinking

Tags: vb6

I am setting up the exe. of vb6 in windows 10, the application always blink when opened, does anyone have an idea about this issue?

Comment: Please what exactly do you mean with "blink"? Never recognized that with my vb6 installation (just getting the this security dialog)

Comment: Are you talking about the VB6 IDE itself, or a program that was created in the VB6 language?

Comment: This may be related to the compatibility settings of the application. If you right click on the exe program (or maybe a link?) and select properties, there should be a tab compatibility. If you have selected compatibility with Windows XP, then it blinks when you open it, because it is modifying the display settings. (By the way, if you don't select this option, the VB6 design window doens't work very well at all).

Comment: Check the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644132/vb6-ide-slowness-and-vbkeysave5-in-the-registry) read ALL of it - it might not appear to apply at first, but I believe it does.