# visual basic has stopped working in

Tags: vb6

i too have the some what semilar problem, i formated my win xp and installed win 7 & cr 9.....
 i made uac off ...installed sp 6,run app in compatibily mode winxp sp3.....
 I get error while compiling "visual basic had stopped working " but my old projects works fine without any issue in winxp and win 7  but new projects are not working in both xp and win7

i guess i am missing any control/reference update or any service pack missing or something else..... please help......
 error massage as below.....
 "visual basic has stopped working"
 Problem signature:
 Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
 Application Name: vb6.exe
 Application Version: 6.0.97.82
 Application Timestamp: 403acf6c
 Fault Module Name: craxddrt9.dll
 Fault Module Version: 9.2.0.448
 Fault Module Timestamp: 3d329028
 Exception Code: c0000094
 Exception Offset: 00360e55
 OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
 Locale ID: 1033
 Additional Information 1: 7e3b
 Additional Information 2: 7e3beb1e9ccf6d519c5b994ca59a280f
 Additional Information 3: 2ac0
 Additional Information 4: 2ac004046dc496f347320c8826a4cbdc

same above error once again with a
 Problem signature:
 Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
 Application Name: vb6.exe
 Application Version: 6.0.97.82
 Application Timestamp: 403acf6c
 Fault Module Name: crheapalloc.dll
 Fault Module Version: 9.2.0.2
 Fault Module Timestamp: 3d242d48
 Exception Code: c0000005
 Exception Offset: 00001a37
 OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
 Locale ID: 1033
 Additional Information 1: 59d4
 Additional Information 2: 59d4d076427db98c37f800e67e6bf4c1
 Additional Information 3: f0f0
 Additional Information 4: f0f042fa45dab8afd44da872cd84204e

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB6: "Visual basic has stopped working"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260508/vb6-visual-basic-has-stopped-working)

Comment: Both of those errors indicate a problem with Crystal Reports.

Comment: still not finding sultion what went wrong with creport

Comment: Gserg possible dublicate of vb??/???

Comment: I guess creport problem

Comment: Do any body have any solution for the above.....